# something like option in wordpress network

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a plugin for Wordpress network and Admin change setting of this plugin and setting saved with ' option ' and I need change option in all of sites. Now is there something like ' option ' and common in all of sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Multisite, if you need to have an option available across all sites, you can use [add_site_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_site_option) / [update_site_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_site_option) and [get_site_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_option).